# stateful sesseion bean @remove

Tags: java, annotations, javabeans

I try to invoke the a method with @Remove annotation from inside the class, but the bean doesn't get deleted. It seems to be that @Remove is only working, if it gets directly called by the client. Is there a way to remove the bean instance by itself?

For example if I have a method:

```
@Remove
public void remove() {}
public void someOtherMethod(){
    remove();
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working or know a workaround to fix it?

best regards,
stefan

Comment: Question is unclear. Answer to the question even moreso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what I was looking for.

```
@Remove(retainIfException = true)
```

So I can define that the instance only gets deleted if no exception rises.